# Editing a custom configuration section in an installer class

Tags: c#, configuration, installation, config

I am trying to update a custom configuration section of a web.config file during the installation of my product in a custom action.  I wanted to use the actual configration classes to do this however when the installer runs it loads my installer class but then the
Configuration.GetSection throw a File Not Found exception as it is trying to load my custom section class from the windows system directory.  I managed to get this to work by copying the required assemblies into the windows system directory but this is not an ideal solution as I cannot guarantee I will always have access to that directory.

How else can I solve this problem?

My update code looks like this

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        //some code here
        webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("MyService");
        MyCustomSection mySection = webconfig.GetSection("MyCustomSection") //<--File Not Found: CustomConfigSections.dll
        //Update config section and save config
    }
}
```

My config file looks like this

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="myCustomSection" type="CustomConfigSections.MyCustomSection, CustomConfigSections" />
     </configSections>
    <myCustomSection>
        <!-- some config here -->
    </myCustomSection>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm having the same issue. I can access the AppSettings fine, but the DLL required to load the ConfigHandler is part of the install, and although appears to be present in the folder, isn't accessible.

I thought that this might help, but no luck so far:

AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);

Comment: I did find another slightly better solution.  You can edit the msi with Orca to change the order it does things so it deploys the assembly and puts it in the GAC before the custom action runs. Still not ideal but better than before.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you would understand the answer the way it is intended.

Assuming that you have setup the installer to have your project output. If Not
Right Click on installer Project click add->Project Output->select your project
and then you can continue using your code.

Moreover if you are using dll except the .net Ones make sure to change there
properties to copylocal = true

If You want to read the element Before Installation use BeforeInstall Event
Handler and try reading your file. ihope your problem will be solved

If in case You want to read the element after installation Right Click On
installer project Click view->customActions->On Install Click Add Custom Action
->Select Application Folder -> Select Primary output from your project and click
ok .

Now Click on primary output and press F4 and in Custom Action Data write

```
/DIR="[TARGETDIR]\"
```

and after that write your code as follows.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
  public ProjectInstaller()
  {
    this.InitializeComponent();
  }
  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
    this.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall);
  }
  void ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
  {
    string path = this.Context.Parameters["DIR"] + "YourFileName.config";
    // make sure you replace your filename with the filename you actually
    // want to read
    // Then You can read your config using XML to Linq Or you can use
    // WebConfigurationManager whilst omitting the .config from the path
  }
```